# Split a word and keep it in a dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary, split

I have a set of words with their POS tags attached, i would like to split and keep it in dictionary.With key as the word and its value as POS tag.
eg: He_PRP bought_VBD it_PRP

Comment: Split them where? Keep in a dictionary using what as the keys and values?

Comment: You should probably start by writing some code.

Comment: Try doing this using google. Post if you have specific issue.

Comment: You expect us to guess what [POS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POS) means here? Piece Of Something?

Comment: give some sample data. also provide the code how you have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
text = "He_PRP bought_VBD it_PRP"
text1 = text.split(' ')
for names in text1:
    words = names.split('_')
    print words
    dictionary[words[0]] = words[1]
print dictionary

The output for this will be
['He', 'PRP']
['bought', 'VBD']
['it', 'PRP']
The dictionary will be 
{'bought': 'VBD', 'it': 'PRP', 'He': 'PRP'}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> wordset = {'He_PRP', 'bought_VBD', 'it_PRP'}
>>> dict(x.split("_") for x in wordset)
{'bought': 'VBD', 'it': 'PRP', 'He': 'PRP'}
```

What should happen if you have the same word with two different POS?